# How to configure nuxt-polyfill for Array.from in Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, polyfills

First question for me: hoping I am following the guide lines :)

I am trying to have my application compatible with IE11.
From what I understood, I need to use Polyfill to do that.

As my application is based on Nuxt.js, I am planning to use nuxt-polyfill package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-polyfill), but I am not able to configure it correctly...

When I am opening my app in IE11, I have the following error:
Object doesn't support property or method 'from'

I have installed nuxt-polyfill as a dependency using npm.
And I tried to configure it to use polyfill.io

Configuration done into nuxt.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    vendor: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'nuxt-polyfill',
      '~/plugins/vuetify.js',
      'vue-i18n'
    ],
    ...
  },
...
  /*
  ** Polyfill configuration
  */
  polyfill: {
    log: true,
    features: [
      {
        require: 'https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?flags=gated&features=Array.from',
        include: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

At the moment, as explained at the beginning, my app is not loading in IE11, I have a blank page with a spinner displayed in the center of it (Like it is loading indefinitely...)

When inspecting the page, in the console, I see the following error:
Object doesn't support property or method 'from'

Comment: default nuxt compile targe is currently IE9. As far as i know you don't need to add  any special package.

Comment: @farincz If I run my web app as is, I have errors in the console when I am using IE 11, and IE is displaying a blank page. So, perhaps Nuxt compile target is IE9, if you are using function not recognized by IE, you need Polyfill...